# Adding imageView as subView

Tags: ios, imageview

How can I add imageView as subView to imageView to it content end ?
And I need to add offset of imageView in its content size

My code not works

```
 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, imageView.subviews.count * _mageView.frame.size.height + _imageView.frame.origin.y , _screenWidth, _image.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the second question first, you might look at `CGRectOffset(CGRect rect, x, y)`
where `rect` is the original rectangle and x and y are the values by which the new rectangle is offset from the original rectangle. You can use this statement to define the value of `imageView.frame`.

For the first question, add the imageView as a subView of the mainView: `[mainView addSubview:imageView]`.